# Find the last TR (group)

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i have the table below

```
<tr id="group_1>...</tr>
   <tr id="el">...</tr>
   <tr id="el">...<tr>
<tr id="group_2"></tr>
   <tr id="el">...</tr>
<tr id="group_1>...</tr>
   <tr id="el">...</tr>
   <tr id="el">...<tr>
```

I need to find the last TR of each group

```
$("tr#group_"+groupID).next("tr#el:last").after("ADD NEW TR");
```

Its not working for me!!

I guess thats because i use for all groups the same id.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well firstly IDs must be unique so behaviour is going to be undefined in your above case.

Secondly, that's a difficult way to group rows. Try using TBODY elements instead>

```
<tbody id="group_2">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...<tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="group_2">
  <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="group_3">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...<tr>
</tbody>
```

and then things get much easier:

```
$("#group_" + groupNum + " tr:last-child").after("add new tr");
```

Thing is, you don't even need to do it this way (using [`after()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after)). It's easier to do it using [`append()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append):

```
$("#group_" + groupNum).append("add new tr");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-use IDs like that.  Try changing it to classes instead.

It might also be worth putting some `<tbody>`s in there:

```
<tr id="group_1>...</tr>
<tbody id="group_1_tbody">
   <tr class="el">...</tr>
   <tr class="el">...<tr>
</tbody>
<tr id="group_2"></tr>
<tbody id="group_2_tbody">
   <tr class="el">...</tr>
</tbody>
```

Then you could do

```
$('group_' + groupID + '_tbody tr:last')
```

or even easier:

```
$('group_' + groupID + '_tbody').append('NEW TR')
```

Comment: +1 what bobince said. As per my answer I think the group_# rows are unnecessary and would suggest the OP just uses groups of TBODY elements rather than mising TBODY and TR elements.

Answer (score 1):

ID's must be unique on a given page. You also don't need to specify the tag when you're identifying an element by ID, since IDs are unique.

A simpler form (once you get rid of those duplicate IDs) would be:

```
$("#group_"+groupID).children("tr:last").after("ADD NEW TR");
```